# Bootstrap not working after minor change to custom.css.scss

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Similarly to this issue:
[rails: any change to custom.css.scss make the app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810434/rails-any-change-to-custom-css-scss-make-the-app-crash)

I have made a change to my custom.css.scss file and all the bootstrap references to colors stopped working. I have manually entered the hex values for these colors now and the app loads, but the classes for my navbar are now not working.

It seems that I have a problem referencing any of the bootstrap classes now for some reason. I also do not understand why making a minor change to a stylesheet has sent my bootstrap styles into a meltdown. I think I must have a setup problem elsewhere.

custom.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;
$gray-darker: #222;
$gray-dark: #333;
$gray: #555;
$gray-light: #999;
$gray-lighter: #eee;
```

Relevant gems

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
```

In addition to this, I recently added the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css file to vendor/assets/stylesheets and the same .js files to use a collapsing panel class.

Any help much appreciated.

application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**UPDATE:**

So I removed and then re-included the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css files and the main navbar styles came back to life. The only things that are still not working are the references to colors and the styles for my drop-down list in the navbar.

Comment: What did you change?  And what doesn't work?

Comment: I was simply trying to change some text size, then none of the bootstrap references seemed to work anymore. I have hacked it a bit so that it is not using the color references now, but the navbar classes are still not working - which is the main issue.

Comment: Add your `application.css` file

Comment: I have added it Michael

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel - you deleted quite a large portion of my post. Did you mean to?

Comment: Yes because that was unrelated codedump.

Comment: OK - the edit you have just made makes more sense to me now. Apologies if I included rather a lot of code originally

Comment: restart your server and see

Comment: or run `rake assets:precompile` with trace

Comment: @RoR - I just deployed the update I got to work to heroku and everything looked the same as when the navbar wasnt working until I ran rake assets:precompile - so that appears to have had something to do with it. Still can't get the other bootstrap classes to work though

Comment: For color i would suggest to use the color code directly without storing them in a variable...what other classes are not working apart from colors and navbar...navbar seems to be fixed right?

Comment: Was your `rake assets:precompile` a success? or it got aborted?

Comment: the rake assets:precompile was successful. I have got everything working now apart from the styles within the drop-down in the nav.

Answer (score 0):

removing bootstrap files from the vendor/assets/javascript and vendor/assets/stylesheets folders solved this issue for me too.